# Parsing error when using const, using Electron 8.2 alongside JavaScript in the Brackets Editor

Tags: javascript, electron

const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')

This is my first line of code, according to the Electron Quick Start Guide, it's a direct copy and paste, however I'm getting this specific error.

ERROR: Parsing error: The Keyword "const" is reserved

However when I run the index.html file everything works fine.

I'm completely new to coding, so if there's an issue with how I worded this please let me know.

Comment: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/first-app follow this tutorial

Comment: Please state what you did to run the code? Did you do `electron .`?

Comment: Maybe your editor or linter is set to an old version of JS, when `const` wasn't supporte yet?